# Iterate every md5 hash possibility

Tags: loops, md5

I'm still pretty new to c# (and programing in general)

I've been trying to attack this with a forloop but im not making much headway as its not simply a numeric iteration its a Hex and not a dec

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
....
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
...
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Comment: Since MD5 hashes are 128 bits long, you would have to iterate over 2¹²⁸ values. You can't actually do that with available hardware. Would you be satisfied with a program that merely *would* iterate over them, theoretically, if allowed to run forever?

Comment: You realize your program would have to print about 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 values, right?  You'll be waiting a *long* time for it to finish.

Comment: Crash, SO is meant to be for real problems that you face. You did _not_ make it clear in your original question that you understood the futility of the exercise, which is why we set you straight. The best thing you could do is change the question to iterate over (for example) an 17-bit value rather than 32. At least the former would complete.

Answer (score 4):

To iterate through every possible value, that's 16<sup>32</sup> iterations, or about 3x10<sup>38</sup>.

At one billion iterations per second, that's going to take you about ten thousand billion billion years :-)

If you somehow gain immortality and can survive the sun burning out in five billion years, here's how you do it.

1/ If you have a 128-or-better bit data type, simply start it at zero and count, outputting the hex value each time.

```
val = 0
while val < 2**128: # watch out for wrapping
    printline hex(val)
    val = val + 1
```

2/ If you have to construct it from smaller data types (like a single character):

```
# init to zero.

dim val[0..32]
foreach index 0..31:
    val[index] = 0

# keep going till done.

while val[32] != 1:
    # print current value.

    foreach index 31..0:
        print hex(val[index])
    printline

    # then increment it.

    carry = 1
    index = 0
    while carry = 1:
        val[index] = val[index] + carry
        if val[index] != 16:
            carry = 0
        index = index + 1
```

Comment: Yea im aware but its just something to keep me busy. My next step is to make the program that the hash input is for multi threaded also fortunately they go a little faster than 1 a second but I get your point

Comment: @Crash893, even if you somehow get a billion-machine cluster up and running, it's _still_ going to take too long.

Comment: the point of the program is not write them all down I just want to know how to do it

Comment: @Crash893, updated with some possibilities, though you may want to test them with a slightly smaller range.